# H264 Hi10P Playback

Tags: video, vlc, kodi

I cannot get Hi10P H264 videos to properly render in VLC or Kodi on my [XU4.](https://wiki.odroid.com/odroid-xu4/odroid-xu4) If the MKV has subtitles they will show up but the video is just a grey wall with slight pixelization at the top, same issue with the video if there are no subtitles. I figured it would work after running

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

but I've had no luck.

### Odroid XU4

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Release:        18.04

Codename:       bionic

Ubuntu Installed Packages: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mxykdjg46qf0kdi/Installed_Packages.txt?dl=0

### Kodi Install Info

Platform: Linux ARM (Thumb) 32-bit

Using Release Kodi x32 build

Kodi compiled Apr 23 2018 by GCC 6.4.0 for Linux ARM (Thumb) 32-bit version 4.15.15 (265999)

### VLC Install Info

3.0.3 Vetinari

### Sample MKV Info

Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)(avc1)

Language: English

Type: Video

Video resolution: 608x480

Buffer dimensions: 608x482

Decoded format: Biplanar 4:2:0 Y/VU

### Sample Hi10P MKV file w/ no subtitles

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3m0vaoasc98szyu/10bit-eldorado.mkv?dl=1

Anyone able to assist?

Comment: What happens if you use an MP4 container instead of MKV? (H.264+AAC based MP4 container format) which is specified as supported by your device?

Comment: Pulled the 10bit-eldorado_track1_eng.avc file out of the MKV container and put it into MP4. Instead of the video being grey it is now black.
...
AVC - https://www.dropbox.com/s/3pvhs6a37swtwig/10bit-eldorado_track1_eng.avc?dl=1
...
MP4 - https://www.dropbox.com/s/elpfmcilq8n2p1n/10bit-eldorado.mp4?dl=1

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem on a fresh install of 18.04 with VLC version 3.0.3 Vetinari (3.0.3-1-0-gc2bb759264)
 but I don't have your hardware. The mkv file doesn't seem to get past the first frame. The MP4 plays as expected. Hopefully someone with your setup can chime in and help you out. Cheers!

Comment: You might try to [reset VLC preferences](https://wiki.videolan.org/VSG:ResetPrefs/) and restarting VLC and if that doesn't work it would likely be prudent to  [report a bug](https://wiki.videolan.org/Report_bugs)